# Kinetic JS Image layering and Animation issue

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm trying to rotate and animate my multiple image layers seperatly ontop of each other. The problem is when I call the animate rotate function on one of the images, my debugger says the image has no function rotate. Here is what I have got

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  });
  var layer1 = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var layer3 = new Kinetic.Layer();
  var layer4 = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var logo4 = new Image();
  var logo3 = new Image();
  var logo2 = new Image();
  var logo1 = new Image();

  var logoRing, logoCross, logoCentreRings, logoCentre;

  var loadCount = 0;
 logo4.onload = function() {
     loadCount ++;
     if(loadCount == 4&& !loaded){
         loaded = true;
         putOnStage();
     }
 };

 logo3.onload = function() {
     loadCount ++;
     if(loadCount == 4&& !loaded){
         loaded = true;
         putOnStage();
     }
 };

 logo2.onload = function() {
     loadCount ++;
     if(loadCount == 4&& !loaded){
         loaded = true;
         putOnStage();
     }
 };

 logo1.onload = function() {
     loadCount ++;
     if(loadCount == 4 && !loaded){
         loaded = true;
         putOnStage();
     }
 };
 var loaded = false;


  logo4.src = "logo_ring.png";
  logo3.src = "logo_cross.png";
  logo2.src = "logo_centre_rings.png";
  logo1.src = "logo_centre.png";
  var logoPosX = 0;
  var logoPosY = 0;
  var logoWidth = 300;
  var logoHeight = 300;

  function putOnStage(){


       logoRing = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: logo4,
          width: logoWidth,
          height: logoHeight
        });
      layer4.add(logoRing);
      stage.add(layer4);


         logoCross = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: logo3,
          width: logoWidth,
          height: logoHeight
        });
      layer3.add(logoCross);
      stage.add(layer3);

         logoCentreRings = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: logo2,
          width: logoWidth,
          height: logoHeight
        });
      layer2.add(logoCentreRings);
      stage.add(layer2);


         logoCentre = new Kinetic.Image({
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
          image: logo1,
          width: logoWidth,
          height: logoHeight
        });
      layer1.add(logoCentre);
      stage.add(layer1);
  }
    var angularSpeed = 360 / 4;
    var rotateCentreRings = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
      var angleDiff = frame.timeDiff * angularSpeed / 1000;
      logoCross.rotate(angleDiff);
    }, layer2);

    rotateCentreRings.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of KineticJS are you using?  Latest version deprecated `rotateDeg` in favour of simply making `rotate` use degrees instead of radians.

Additionally, you are creating and starting the animation before the images are loaded. This is why `logoCross` is undefined when you try to rotate it.  Move that inside of `putOnStage` and it should work.

```
function putOnStage(){


     logoRing = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: logo4,
        width: logoWidth,
        height: logoHeight
      });
    layer4.add(logoRing);
    stage.add(layer4);


       logoCross = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: logo3,
        width: logoWidth,
        height: logoHeight
      });
    layer3.add(logoCross);
    stage.add(layer3);

       logoCentreRings = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: logo2,
        width: logoWidth,
        height: logoHeight
      });
    layer2.add(logoCentreRings);
    stage.add(layer2);


       logoCentre = new Kinetic.Image({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        image: logo1,
        width: logoWidth,
        height: logoHeight
      });
    layer1.add(logoCentre);
    stage.add(layer1);
    var angularSpeed = 360 / 4;
  var rotateCentreRings = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
    var angleDiff = frame.timeDiff * angularSpeed / 1000;
    logoCross.rotate(angleDiff);
  }, layer2);

  rotateCentreRings.start();
}
```

Comment: version 5.0.1, I used rotateDeg and it gave me "Cannot call method 'rotateDeg' of undefined"

Comment: Thank you, I also had the wrong layer selected to animate too. :) but your solution helped